# Connect to HSQLDB 2.5 via Windows ODBC PostgreSQL driver

Tags: odbc, hsqldb

I am having a problem configuring the Windows PostgreSQL ODBC driver to connect to HSQLDB 2.5.0.  As per the HSQLDB documentation I have installed version 11.01 of the PostgreSQL ODBC driver.  When I test the connection from the ODBC Data Source Administrator I see the following in the ODBC log file:
 `[0.000]Driver Version='11.01.0000,May 24 2019' linking 1915 dynamic Multithread library
[0.000]PQconnectdbParams: host='localhost' port='9001' dbname='test' user='test' sslmode='disable' password='test'
[0.109]PQsendQuery: 000000000033BCA0 'SET DateStyle = 'ISO';SET extra_float_digits = 2;show transaction_isolation'
[0.109] (ERROR) 42501 'user lacks privilege or object not found: DATESTYLE'
[1.157]PQfinish: 000000000033BCA0`

It looks like the driver is sending a "SET DateStyle" command that HSQLDB doesn't understand.  I've tried changing all the datasource options with no success.  I have tried both the Unicode and ANSI versions of the driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation on the web site is for version 2.5.1 which is in Release Candidate stage. You can download a snapshot jar from http://hsqldb.org/download/