# HSQLDB JDBC driver for connecting from Excel

Tags: excel, jdbc, odbc, hsqldb

Is there an HSQLDB JDBC driver that can be used to connect to HSQLDB from Excel (on Windows 10)?

I tried the ODBC option according to the documentation [here](https://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/odbc-chapt.html#odbc_windows_config-sect) (with version 11.01 of the PostgreSQL ODBC driver, Unicode version - as stated), but whatever I do I can't get it to work whatever I do (the connection test passes, but I keep getting SQL query errors when trying to connect a data source from Excel. Tried Access too - same result. After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62196145/connect-to-hsqldb-2-5-via-windows-odbc-postgresql-driver), I also tried to find out where the queries sent to the ODBC driver, enabled all the logging from the ODBC driver setup in Windows administrative tools but the queries from Excel/Access don't seem to get logged there at all).

After a couple of hours I decided to try to figure out if I can connect Excel to it via JDBC instead. ChatGPT *insists* that it can be done (even after repeatedly asking if it's sure)... perhaps it's one of those hallucinations of his...

Answer (score 0):

When I try to connect Excel to HSQLDB with Postgress ODBC driver without specifying an SQL statement I always get "ODBC: ERROR [HY000] Error while executing the query".
But if I specify a statement in advanced options of the "From ODBC" dialog, just anything like "select * from test_table;" I get the result with no error.
The HSQLDB documentation says "it does not yet support database metadata" so I think you should always specify an SQL statement.